# Extracting using a string pattern in Regex- Python

Tags: python, regex

Cant we give a string in the Regex? For example, `re.compile('((.*)?=<Bangalore>)')`, in the below code i have mentioned `<Bangalore>` but its not displaying.

I want to extract the text before Bangalore.

```
import re

regex = re.compile('((.*)?=<>)')

line = ("Kathick Kumar, Bangalore who was a great person and lived from 29th 

March 1980 - 21 Dec 2014")

result = regex.search(line)

print(result)
```

Desired output: Kathick Kumar, Bangalore

Comment: Why on earth do you think that the regex you're suggesting would capture your desired output? It's looking for `'=<Bangalore>'` *literally*, which doesn't exist in your `line`.

Comment: I'm new to regex dude, that is why getting a clarity on how should i approach this. Any help on this would be great. :)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: It didn't match because, there is no `=` or `<` or even `>` in `line`. You need to read more about regex before attempting

Comment: Ok sure, i will do that. But before that can you tell me what will be the apt regex for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `(.*)(?:Bangalore)` pattern

```
>>> line = ("Kathick Kumar, Bangalore who was a great person and lived from 29thMarch 1980 - 21 Dec 2014")
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile('(.*)(?:Bangalore)')
>>> result = regex.search(line)
>>> print(result.group(0))
Kathick Kumar, Bangalore
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Nishan, but will this {print(result.group(0))} work if there are multiple lines in a text file? I doubt it would.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(.*Bangalore)')
result = regex.search(line)

>>> print result.groups()
('Kathick Kumar, Bangalore',)
```